# HERE Maps working on FrameLayout popBackStack() not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, here-api

I am working on FrameLayouts to support the Activity in loading different fragments. First fragment is the MapFragment and the other one is the MapDownloadManagerFragment for maps.

I have an issue about the popBackStack() method. MapFragment doesn't show any maps. It show only white background after the popBackStack() executed.

Here's the code:

```
 


    private MapFragment mMapFragment = null;
    private FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
    private MapDownloadManagerFragment mMapDownloadManagerFragment;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          if (mMapFragment == null) {
                mMapFragment = new MapFragment();
            }

            mFragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_frame_layout, mMapFragment, mFragmentID);
            mFragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            mFragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    private void onClickMenutItem() {
mMapDownloadManagerFragment = new MapDownloadManagerFragment();

                mFragmentTransaction =  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame_layout, mMapDownloadManagerFragment, mdmFragmentID);
                mFragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                mFragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Back stack count " +  getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
        if( getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            finish();
        } else {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    }
```

Is there anyone who encountered this problem? I need your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now I fixed this issue by removing current MapFragment and replace it with new MapFragment.

```
 mFragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            mFragmentTransaction.remove(mMapFragment);

            mMapFragment = null;
            mMapFragment = new MapFragment();
            mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_frame_layout, mMapFragment, mFragmentID);
            mFragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            mFragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Still figuring on how to implement it in a best way.